# Word frequency not accurate after text stemming

Tags: r, hunspell

Thank you for taking the time to read my post. Newbie here and this here is my first R script with some sample data.

```
library(tm)
library(hunspell)
library(stringr)

docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource('He is a nice player, She could be a better player. Playing basketball is fun. Well played! We could have played better. Wish we had better players!'))

input <- strsplit(as.character(docs), " ")
input <- unlist(input)
input <- hunspell_stem(input)
input <- word(input,-1)

input <- VCorpus(VectorSource(input))
docs <- input

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
```

This returns the following results:

> character0 48       better 3  play 3 basketball 1 description 1
>   fun 1         head 1        hour 1 language 1 meta 1 min 1 nice 1
>   origin 1 well 1 wish 1 year 1

Expected results:

> better 3  play 3 basketball 1 fun 1         language 1 nice 1 well 1
>   wish 1

Not sure where these words are coming from (character0, description, meta, language, etc) and if there's a way to get rid of them?

Basically what I'm trying to do is apply stemming on a corpus (data source sql server table) with hunspell and display them in a word cloud later on. Any help would be appreciated. GD

Comment: If you go through your code line by line, you see that `input <- word(input,-1)` breaks things. `hunspell_stem` returns a list structure, where each element corresponds to one word; however, it may return more than one stem for one word. You may want to skip your middle part and do `dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(stemming =  function(x) sapply(hunspell_stem(x), tail, 1)))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works well for the above example but if I enter something else, I get the error message below:
`library(tm)
library(hunspell)

docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource('Thanks lukeA for your help!'))

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(stemming = function(x) sapply(hunspell_stem(x), tail, 1)))
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)`

`Error in table(txt) : all arguments must have the same length`

Is that because none of the words have stems in the string?

Comment: That's because there's no stem returned for lukea. So you not only have to check for multiple stems, but also for no stem if you insist on hunspell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why the example in your comment fails:

```
library(tm) 
library(hunspell) 
hunspell_stem(strsplit('Thanks lukeA for your help!', "\\W")[[1]])
# [[1]]
# [1] "thank"
# 
# [[2]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "for"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "your"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "help"
```

And here is one way to make it work:

```
docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource('Thanks lukeA for your help!')) 
myStem <- function(x) { 
  res <- hunspell_stem(x)
  idx <- which(lengths(res)==0)
  if (length(idx)>0)
    res[idx] <- x[idx]
  sapply(res, tail, 1) 
}
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(stemming = myStem)) 
m <- as.matrix(dtm) 
sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
  # for help! lukea thank  your 
  #   1     1     1     1     1
```

This will return the original token if there's no stem, and the last stem if there are multiple stems.

Comment: Thank you again. I don't really understand why replacing the test string above with "test" would fail. Hunspell returns "t" as the stem so I would expect "t" to be returned. 

If I had "testing" as the string it would work fine as  the stem returned would be "test".

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: The function returns the last stem of both stems "test" and "t" (`tail`). You could return the first using `head`. However, "t" gets filtered by the default word length filter. That's the reason why it fails. You could do ` TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(stemming = myStem, wordLengths = c(-Inf, Inf)))` do disable filtering by word length. See `?termFreq`.